# __doPostBack not working for updatepanel on page where enableviewstate=false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, viewstate, dopostback

I have an update panel on a page, and am using `__doPostBack` on a control inside the updatepanel called from javascript to do a postback and update the panel.

Everything works fine, until I set `enableviewstate=false` on the page.

The javascript still fires, but nothing happens on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

well i don't understand but where lies your problem but this worked for me with a quick code

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="result">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ID="udpnl" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="UnClicked" OnClick="btn_click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <input type="button" value="DoPartialPost" onclick="__doPostBack('btn','')" />
    </div>
```

The code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btn_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        btn.Text = "Clicked";
        udpnl.Update();
    }
```